# Cannot clone project from github

Tags: git, android-studio, github

I want to clone next project:
[android-architecture](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture)

In github I got the [HTTPS link](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture.git) to clone project.
In Android Studio: File - New - Project from Version Control - Github.
But when I cloned the project, I see next in Project window:

[image]

And no project files.

Moreover - files are not present in Explorer:
[image]

**What am I doing wrong?**

PS. When I press "Download ZIP" in github - everything is ok.
PPS. Tried to clone via terminal (not Studio) - result is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the ReadMe of the project, specifically to [this section](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture#opening-a-sample-in-android-studio) (Opening a sample in Android Studio).

Since they don't have any project on master branch you need to checkout a different branch (see this [link](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/wiki/Samples-at-a-glance)).

Hope this helps!!